# Installing Canopy on Windows 8

Tags: canopy

I am trying to install Canopy and I got this message throw the instalation process:

```
Acces is denied. Please change the permisions and restart Canopy.
```

When I click OK, I see another message:

```
Canopy was not able to install User Python Enviroment at 'C:\...'. Please submit a bug report.
```

When I finally open Editor in Canopy, I can see that "Python kernel has crashed", and I cant type anything.

What should I do? I tried three time everything from this page:

https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001433803-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy%20v2

But still nothing.

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit a report from the Canopy help menu => Feedback / bugs. The report will include some detail about your setup and will allow Enthought Support to make specific suggestions.